# swagger-ui Existing application - JBoss EAP 7.4

Tags: swagger, wildfly, jboss7.x

I'm trying to integrate our RESTEasy API with swagger-ui to allow external module developers to test against our interface.

My knowledge is a little hazy when it comes to the support of existing APIs. The service containing the REST API is an application packaged into an *.ear file deployed on a JBoss EAP 7.4 Server.

I deployed the *.dist folder of swagger-ui on the undertow web-server and swagger-ui is accessible. So far so good.

My question is now: is it at all possible to have swagger detect the resource contents of the *.ear file without my having to configure the swagger.json manually, or, alternatively, package it into a *.war file and deploy it on the EAP?

If so, how to proceed? Do I need the swagger-codegen, the inspector oder will just the UI somehow work?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger can't automatically detect those. But if you're already exposing the `swagger.json` file in your ear, then maybe you can just change the swagger-ui source to look for that specific address when starting up. You should change the `url` property in the following code to point to your own:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  
      //<editor-fold desc="Changeable Configuration Block">
      window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        "dom_id": "#swagger-ui",
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout",
        queryConfigEnabled: true,
        validatorUrl: "https://validator.swagger.io/validator",
        url: "https://YOUR_SERVER/CONTEXT_PATH/swagger.json" // <-- CHANGE THIS URL
      })
      
      //</editor-fold>
};
```

Also if you're using a more recent versions of the WildFly, there is a dedicated subsystem named `microprofile-openapi-smallrye` that you can enable to generate the `json` file for you automatically. You can find more details about it in [this tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/eclipse/eclipse-microservices/getting-started-with-openapi-on-wildfly/).